# How to reset application badge number in react native push notification?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I'm looking reset *application badge number* in **react-native-push-notification** when the user opens the app but can't find the method anywhere in the docs, any idea?

Comment: try `setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0)` , reference: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#setapplicationiconbadgenumber

Answer (score 7):

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#setapplicationiconbadgenumber

```
  PushNotificationIOS.getApplicationIconBadgeNumber((num)=>{ // get current number
        if(num >= 1){
            PushNotificationIOS.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0) //set number to 0
        }
    });
```

`PushNotificationIOS` imported from react native

Answer (score 6):

You can add this to your AppDelegate.m, which will set badge count to 0 when app is opened or goes into the background.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
 }

-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
 }
```

Or

Within app.js (if using react hooks), will also reset badge count when app becomes active or goes into background

```
import { AppState } from 'react-native';

 useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
    };
  }, []);

  const _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios' && nextAppState === 'active' || nextAppState === 'background') {
      PushNotificationIOS.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The appdelegate.m-option is better for me, because it doesn't require the PushNotificationIOS library, and it would be kinda useless to install just for this one little feature.

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';


...
...


  
PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0); //magic
```